# 2d array throwing "list indices must be integers, not list" python

Tags: python, list, multidimensional-array, pygame

I'm trying to make a 2d list in python, i.e. a 2d array, for a game in pygame.  The idea is that a new square will be drawn until I have a grid of squares.  This is the code I have so far:

```
grid = []
width = 10
height = 10
x = -width
y = -height
index = 0
while index < height:
    grid.append([])
    index += 1
for i in grid:
    y += height
    for j in grid[i]:
        x += width
        grid_square = Grid_square(x,y)
        grid[i].append(grid_square)
```

the problem is when I run it I get typeError: list indices must be integers, not list on the line "for j in grid[i]".  This sort of thing would work fine in javascript, but I've never made a 2d list in python before.  How can I iterate through a 2d list and make a grid of my Grid_square objects in a more elegant way that doesn't throw any errors?

Comment: what do you think `i` is? what is the error telling you about it? did you at least try to log it to confirm one way or the other?

Comment: (also, never do that in javascript)

Comment: sorry, I thought i was just an index variable like in javascript, I overlooked this.  never do what in javascript?

Comment: nope. in JS, `for .. in` iterates on the properties of an object. indices of an array happen to be properties, but your array could have others, and your array could have gaps, which are not going to be iterated through.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `for j in i`, not `for j in grid[i]`. `i` is already a `list` - no need for indexing.

To get the structure you're looking for, you can replace the entire code snippet in your question with this:

```
width = 10
height = 10
grid = [[Grid_square(column*height, row*width) for column in range(10)] for row in range(10)]
```

This is equivalent to the following nested loops:

```
width = 10
height = 10
grid = []
for row in range(10):
    c = []
    for column in range(10):
        c.append(Grid_square(column*height, row*width))
    grid.append(c)
```

Comment: ok thanks i fixed that, but now my while loop runs infinitely.  any thoughts as to why?

Comment: That would be because you're appending to the `list` while walking through it, so there's always more to go.

Comment: Exactly what structure are you trying to create in the `for i in grid:` loop? Could you add an example to your question?

Comment: but my while loop isn't walking through any list, so why would it keep going?

Comment: Are you sure the problem is with the `while` loop? Because it looks like it's happening in the `for` loop.

Comment: Is your goal a 10x10 2D array of `Grid` objects, each of which contains its coordinates?

Comment: yes, each of which is the width and height apart, so it forms a checkerboard

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84757/discussion-between-user3150635-and-tigerhawkt3).